# Box2d :What is the best approach to build static Box2d smooth curve line

Tags: box2d

i want to know what is the best approach to simulate smooth curved line as static body 
it will be like path for car to drive .
something like this :
http://www.freeriderhd.com/

how does its box2d static body are constructed ?
Thanks

Comment: in which language are u using box2d ?

Comment: c++ but i can understand any